# Vim command for "change inside next occurance of ..."

Tags: vim

I'm sure quite a few of you have typed `ci(` or `ci"` only to have it fail because you aren't currently inside the parentheses or quotes.

Is there a variant of the ci command that changes inside the next occurrence of a text object, instead of the current one? I'm thinking kind of like a shortcut for `f(` followed by `ci(`, or is this simply the most efficient way of doing things?

Comment: FWIW, `ci"` doesn't fail if you aren't currently inside of the quotes. It behaves slightly differently then `ci(`.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I use it only when cursor is before the first `"`. otherwise you will be surprised... try this`"foo"bar"bl[I]ah"blahbla"`

Comment: There is no such built-in function. However you can create mapping if it is important to you.

Comment: @Kent I was referring to [this behavior](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19/why-does-ci-and-ci-behave-differently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to do this. However, you can do this with some vimscript.

```
onoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a')<cr>
xnoremap an :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('a')<cr>
onoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i')<cr>
xnoremap in :<c-u>call <SID>NextTextObject('i')<cr>

function! s:NextTextObject(motion)
  echo
  let c = nr2char(getchar())
  exe "normal! f".c."v".a:motion.c
endfunction
```

Here is how you would use this:

```
(bar) (foo) (baz)
        ^
```

Type `din(`. Here is what your text would look like after:

```
(bar) (foo) ()
```

Think of this as delete inner next `(` ). This is extremely useful!

Comment: I'm making this a CW because I didn't come up with it. Thanks goes to this guy: https://gist.github.com/AndrewRadev/1171559#file-next_motion_mapping-vim

Comment: This looks like it'll do the trick. I'll have to double check that it works, but this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [`target.vim`](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) seems to provide this functionality on top of adding more text objects.

Example:

```
<CURSOR_HERE>
return {
    'wellle/targets.vim',
    event = "InsertEnter",
}
```

Typing `ci'` will get you to:

```
return {
    '<CURSOR_HERE>',
    event = "InsertEnter",
}
```

The plugin provides more options/text objects; if interested, read their readme file.